# How can I use a string to reference a symbol?

Tags: scheme, racket

The following code will generate `#f` and `#t`

```
1: (define dict (hash 1 'a 2 'b ))
2: (hash? (string->symbol "dict"))
3: (symbol? (string->symbol "dict"))
```

Basically, I want the string `"dict"` will be turned into the hash `dict` defined in line 1. How can I do that?

Comment: put `dict` into a hash-table so you can look it up

Comment: @ Jeremy: Thanks for the title edit. I think it is precisely what I meant to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to `eval` the result of `string->symbol`, like so:

```
> (define dict 5)
> (eval (string->symbol "dict"))
5
```

However, getting `eval` involved is almost never the right thing to do. A much better way to associate strings with values is to use a hashtable as @yi_H suggests:

```
> (define ht (make-hash))
> (hash-set! ht "dict" 5)
> (hash-ref ht "dict")
5
```

**Update**: I missed the `[racket]` tag initially; the example should now work with `#lang racket`.

Comment: Also, note that this answer is using R6RS function, which is not the default Racket names.  For `#lang racket`, use `make-hash`, and `hash-set!` etc.

Comment: +1 to "getting `eval` involved is almost never the right thing to do". The limitations of `eval` in Racket are discussed here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html

Comment: @Eli Thanks for the R6RS vs. Racket catch.